# owl:ObjectProperty and reasoning

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege, inference

In my ontology, I have two individuals of type `abc:Invention` :

```
abc:InventionA rdf:type abc:Invention .
abc:InventionB rdf:type abc:Invention .
```

and 2 individuals of type `abc:MarketSector`, linked with an object property `abc:includedIn` :

```
abc:MrktSctrA rdf:type abc:MarketSector .
abc:MrktSctrB rdf:type abc:MarketSector .    
abc:MrktSctrB abc:includedIn MrktSctrA .
```

Currently, InventionA and InventionB are linked with, respectively MrktSctrA and MrktSctrB via an object property `abc:targets` :

```
abc:InventionA abc:targets abc:MrktSctrA .
abc:InventionB abc:targets abc:MrktSctrB .
```

Is it possible to create an object property `abc:commonObjectivesWith` equivalent to the following statement ?

> If an **Invention targets a MarketSector**, and another **Invention
>   targets another MarketSector**, and **any of these MarketSectors is
>   included in the other MarketSector**, then those two **Inventions have
>   common objectives**.

Then, if I start my reasoner on this ontology, it can infer

```
abc:InventionA abc:commonObjectivesWith abc:InventionB
```

Is this possible ? Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a SWRL rule as shown in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24574105/1281433), but that requires a reasoner that can use SWRL rules.  You can also do this in OWL 2 DL using subproperty chains.  You've got this situation, where the solid arrows are relationships in your data, and the dotted arrow is what you want to infer:

[image: image of graph (see revision history for ASCII art)]

You can represent this with an OWL 2 DL subproperty chain axiom of the form (first abstract, then in Protégé with the resulting ontology):

> targets **o** includes **o** **inverse**(targets) **SubPropertyOf** common

[image: protégé screenshot]

```
@prefix :      <https://stackoverflow.com/q/24569317/1281433/paths#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

<https://stackoverflow.com/q/24569317/1281433/paths> aowl:Ontology .
:includesClassification a owl:ObjectProperty .
:targets                a owl:ObjectProperty .
:commonObjectivesWith
        a owl:ObjectProperty ;
        owl:propertyChainAxiom  ( :targets :includesClassification [ owl:inverseOf :targets ] ) .
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I find out how :
On Protégé 4, I clicked Window -> Views -> Ontology Views -> Rules.
In Rules pane, I added the rule :

```
includesClassification(?mA, ?mB), targets(?invA, ?mA), targets(?invB, ?mB) -> commonObjectives(?invA, ?invB)
```